# Makefile 'if' condition with regexp

Tags: regex, makefile

I need to do something like this:

```
case `uname -m` in
i?86) echo "CFLAGS += -march=i486 -mtune=native" > configparms ;;
esac
```

But I need to do this in makefile for a particular target. I have not found a method to make an if condition with a regular expression.

I tried this:

```
ifeq ($(shell uname -m), i*86)
```

But it does not work.
Even

```
ifeq ($(shell uname -m), i686)
```

does not work.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

```
if uname -m | grep -Eq 'i.86'
then
  echo 'Yesss!'
fi
```

Comment: Makefile syntax is not the same as bash. You cannot simply embed bash code.

Answer (score 7):

Using Makefile built-in conditionals (as opposite of [Ωmega's Bash solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11328602/4411354))

```
ifeq ($(shell uname -m | egrep "i.86"),) # empty result from egrep
    @echo "No match"
else
    @echo "Match"
endif
```

See here using this approach to validate a Git tag https://gist.github.com/jesugmz/a155b4a6686c4172048fabc6836c59e1.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this. Just make sure your `case` statement is "on one line" by escaping the end of the line:

```
uname -m | grep -E 'i.86' >/dev/null \
case $$? in \
   0) echo Matches \
   ;; \
   1) echo No match \
   ;; \
esac
```

Also, note that `$?` is actually `$$?` to prevent `make` from trying to expand it before passing it to the interpreter.